# Google Sites 403 Forbidden: Insufficient storage quota

Tags: google-api, google-sites

I'm developing an application in which I've wrote a function (.NET) to create a Google Site.

It works perfectly fine, up until I'm testing for a while and have created and deleted several sites in a relatively short time span: I eventually end up with the `403 Forbidden: Insufficient storage quota` response. It's usually fixed after a day or 2, but it's not the first time I've encountered this issue, so I thought I should share it and see if anyone else has encountered the same thing.

I've read the article about Google Sites storage quota at https://support.google.com/sites/answer/96770?hl=en, but it doesn't seem like I've hit any of the quota. The sites that are created are empty templates, so the site quota can't be reached. They're located under a https://sites.google.com/a/ domain.

To make sure it isn't a configuration issue, I've tested the raw requests in the OAuth 2.0 Playground which can be found on https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/, resulting in the same error response.

Steps to reproduce:

1. I've created multiple sites under the same Google Sites domain
2. I'm eventually unable to make more sites due to the "403 Forbidden - Insufficient storage quota" error
3. Even after deleting multiple sites, the issue still persists

Because the code I've written is quite long and not really relevant, I've made a GitHub snippet for the ones who are interested:
https://gist.github.com/Cyanized/8ef24ff1de6454fd4ccd6466d591a53d

Is there something I'm overlooking, or is it a known issue/bug?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Google Apps Support, and they've linked me an article with the answer.

The maximum amount of sites you can create on an account in a week is 5. If you go over that amount, you will get the error I mentioned. When the week is over, you're able to create more sites again.

This is a global restriction and can't be changed at the current time.

Reference:
https://support.google.com/sites/answer/117477?hl=en